# Syntax error in UPDATE Statement SQL updating MS Access database C#

Tags: c#, sql, database

Can anyone spot the syntax error in this statement. It is updating an MS ACCESS database in a Visual Studio project via C#.

```
string sql = "UPDATE Contacts SET Environment=\"" + Environment + "\", Group=\"" + Group + "\", Platform=\"" + Platform + "\", Language=\"" + Language + "\", URL=\"" + URL + "\", Usernamex=\"" + Usernamex + "\", Passwordx=\"" + Passwordx + "\", Contact_Name=\"" + Contact_Name + "\", Email=\"" + Email + "\" + WHERE ID=" + ID;
```

I'm sure I'm just not excaping something correctly.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You may want to just prefix the string with `@` and strip out all the escapes.

Comment: string literals should be in `'` instead of `"`, also - your query is vulnerable to sql injection

Answer (score 2):

```
string sql = 

"UPDATE Contacts SET Environment= @Environment, Group=@Group, Platform=@Platform, Language=@Language, URL=@URL, Usernamex=@Usernamex, Passwordx=@Passwordx, Contact_Name=@Contact_Name, Email=@Email WHERE ID=@ID";
```

After that use

```
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
```

For other Paramters you will need same line of code but instead of @ID->@Group and etc ...

In this case the CommandText will be more readable for debug and you will be protected from sql injection !